# 3 column layout using divs, where does the text go?

Tags: html

I have seen the many questions on here regarding 3 column layouts using div tags, which is what i want to achieve.

However I can't work out where I enter the text and other content, for instance I want column 1 to be related to Wedding Photography, column 2 to be related to Portrait Photography, and column 3 to have my clickable social media buttons (I have the code for these) and a few words about them.

I'm used to template sites but I want to customize my zenfolio website beyond their very dated template.

Comment: Pop some basic HTML into your question, Mark, and you'll get more concrete advice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">

#left_wrapper {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#middle_wrapper {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#right_wrapper {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

#left {
  padding: 10px 60px;
}

#right {
  padding: 10px 60px;
}

#middle {
  padding: 10px 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="left_wrapper"> 
  <div id="left">
  <p>This is the left text :  This is the left text : 
    This is the left text :  This is the left text :
    This is the left text :  This is the left text :
    This is the left text :  This is the left text :
  </p>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="middle_wrapper"> 
  <div id="middle">
  <p>This is the middle text : this is the middle text 
    This is the middle text : this is the middle text 
    This is the middle text : this is the middle text 
    This is the middle text : this is the middle text 
    This is the middle text : this is the middle text 
  </p> 
  </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right_wrapper">
    <div id="right"> 
   <p>This is the right text : This is the right text 
     This is the right text : This is the right text 
    This is the right text : This is the right text 
    This is the right text : This is the right text 
   </p>
   </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The wrappers define tree columns, but the other divs ( left, right, middle ) allow easier manipulation.

You can add spacing between the columns with padding ( as I have added in the code example ), but the padding will be on the new divs, not the wrappers.

There is an another way, which actually divides a div into columns.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css"> 
.newspaper
{
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer does not support the column-count property.</p>

<div class="newspaper">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

(Glad I helped)

Comment: That's brilliant thank you. do you know how i can leave a little more space between the columns, do you call it padding?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its using bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/, you can easily implement this and can use lot of components of bootstrap.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Demo Layout with 3 columns</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type='text/css'>
        .container-fluid > .sidebar
        {
            position: relative;
            top: 0;
            left: auto;
            width: 220px;
        }
        .left
        {
            float: left;
        }
        .right
        {
            float: right;
        }
        .fixed-fluid
        {
            margin-left: 240px;
        }
        .fluid-fixed
        {
            margin-right: 240px;
            margin-left: auto !important;
        }
        .fixed-fixed
        {
            margin: 0 240px;
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        body
        {
            padding-top: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topbar">
        <div class="topbar-inner">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="brand" href="#">My Demo Layout</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="sidebar left">
            <div class="well">
                <h5>
                    Left Siderbar Menu</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Product</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sidebar right">
            <div class="well">
                <h5>
                    News</h5>
                <p>
                    News About Project !! About Project !! About Project !!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content fixed-fixed">
            <!-- Main block center -->
            <div class="hero-unit">
                <h1>
                    About Project!!</h1>
                <p>
                    About Project !! About Project !! About Project !! About Project !! About Project
                    !! About Project !! About Project !! About Project !!</p>
                <p>
                    <a class="btn primary large">More &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <footer>
          <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>
        </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this website it generates structured CSS code on the fly.

1. http://www.zurb.com/playground/css-grid-builder (my choice)
2. http://www.thenoodleincident.com/tutorials/box_lesson/boxes.html

Comment: That's great thanks, but again, i'm new to this, so don't know where to enter the text.